# Threejs remove previous rendered scene

Tags: javascript, three.js

I created a renderer scene in threejs. When I load a model for the second time, I want to remove the previous rendered scene from th canvas. Is there any possible solution in threejs???

Comment: Clear the canvas maybe?

Comment: But when i open the threejs editor addon option in chrome inspect element, it is not removing

Comment: @Bálint But when i open the threejs editor addon option in chrome inspect element, it is not removing

Comment: Wait, do you want to remove the objects or clear the screen?

Comment: @Bálint I need to clear the canvas and load a new model

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can clear the canvas using

```
[WebGLRenderer].context.clear(16640); // 16640 is (COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)
// Replace [WebGLRenderer] with your instance of the renderer
```

Comment: Issue is solved. I used scene.getObjectByName( ) , obtained the mesh name and solved the problem

Answer (score 0):

I found it useful to create groups of objects and then add the group to the scene. When you have to clear the scene, you can get the group and remove its children and then remove the group itself.